# Nginx only allowing GET requests

Tags: nginx, post, configuration, get

I configured Nginx to handle backend and frontend services through https. It is working fine except for the backend (/api/v1) where only the GET method is working. If I send a POST request, I get a 405 (Method not allowed).

Since the backend is working perfectly fine locally, I assumed there must be some problem with the nginx configuration. I tried adding "allow all" to the location /api/v1, but it makes no difference.

This is my nginx defaul.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api/v1 {
        allow all;
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000/api/v1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```